# How to filter listA with objects based on values from listB?

Tags: android, kotlin

I got listA

```
val listA = listOf<Data>(Data(name="ben",age=31),Data(name="sam",age=30),Data(name="pam",age=33))
```

I got listB

```
val listB = listOf<Data>(Data(name="ben",age=31),Data(name="pam",age=33))
```

So I need listC that will include only objects that has same name/age in both lists. If name/age are not the same that objects must be excluded.

Comment: _val result = listA.intersect(listB)_ or: _val result = listB.intersect(listA)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your objects are data class you can directly use the list.intersect. Otherwise, you should override equals() method.

If you want to filter by some properties not with all object again you can override equals() method.

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to give an example of equals overriding?

Comment: _return other is Data && other.name == name && other.age == age_